# Inserting time section in date field using oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a procedure in oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE ONE
    (
    p_GUID IN ONE.GUID%TYPE,
    p_START_DATE IN ONE.START_DATE%TYPE,
    p_END_DATE IN ONE.END_DATE%TYPE,
    p_RETURN OUT INTEGER
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_GUID, to_date(p_START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date(p_END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_RETURN:= 1;
END;
```

edit, because people seem to saying to try this (this does not work either, i tried to use to_date (above example) to try and fix the problem):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE ONE
    (
    p_GUID IN ONE.GUID%TYPE,
    p_START_DATE IN ONE.START_DATE%TYPE,
    p_END_DATE IN ONE.END_DATE%TYPE,
    p_RETURN OUT INTEGER
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_GUID, p_START_DATE, p_END_DATE);
    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_RETURN:= 1;
END;
```

When call it from c# (with DateTime.NOW for example) - it fails.

It only seems to work if the start date and end date are in the format of 05-apr-2013. but how do I get the time in there as well as in the input?

If I replace

```
p_START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

With

```
'2013-05-13 12:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

This works, but upon calling the procedure from c# it fails.

Also If I manually run the procedure from db client I still have to input 05-apr-2013 and only that works. I can not input the time as it fails if I try so.

Start date and end date are DATE type in oracle db.

--

Depending what I try I get different messages.

As I investigated, it seems to have something to do with this:

```
SELECT value FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Which returns:

```
DD-MON-RR
```

And I cannot change that as am not the db owner.

--

**so how to get the time part in there?**

Here is the complete SQL:

```
select parameter, value from nls_session_parameters;
```

Which returns:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  . 
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Comment: Can you change the sessions date format?  e.g. ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD';

Comment: possibly, yes. but is that the only way?

Comment: It is probably something like p_START_DATE is being treated as a DATE and not a DATETIME. What is your create table definition for START_DATE and END_DATE?

Comment: created it as datetime in oracle sql dev. in the database it is date(7)

Comment: Please remove exception handling and tell us exact Oracle error message.

Comment: Execution of method with IN params (inParamName=p_GUID; inParamValue=6bb4d749-1d07-4f7c-b7f7-8b41dba04043; inParamName=p_START_DATE; inParamValue=4/5/2013 3:29:15 PM; inParamName=p_END_DATE; inParamValue=4/5/2013 3:29:15 PM; ) failed with exception: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x00001996): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ONE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: As I tell in my answer it's client-side error.

Comment: @ThinkJet bw the damn answer was discovered just now by me :P the p_RETURN OUT INTEGER has to be on the first place for some reason in the procedure. just fyi ;) i tried everything client side and then in the last ditch try arranged the params differently and it seems to work.

Comment: @b0x0rz Congratulations! Your code are working! :) Thank you for explanation about real cause of error. Hope it's helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no need to convert function to `DATE` type. It's already date.
Just insert value passed in parameter:

```
    INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_GUID, p_START_DATE, p_END_DATE);
```

**Update**

But if variant above don't work and you see raised error, stored procedure parameters definition must be checked on clients side. Can you verify that `p_START_DATE` parameter on client side have DateTime type?

**Update 2**

There are error on client side.
Try to initialize date parameters like in example below:

```
OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter();
p1.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
p1.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Reason of error probably is C# component treats parameter as string and convert it to string with default OS format, then passes it to Oracle with query. Oracle trying to parse that string to date type as specified in definition of `ONE` stored procedure and fails with that because expects default format from  NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameters.

**Update 3**

Real cause of error explained by @b0x0rz in comments (wrong return type). Anyway it's client-side mistake...

Comment: as i said as a comment to the previous answer:: yeah, INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES (p_GUID, p_START_DATE, p_END_DATE); does not work either. this was the original. the only reason why i did to_date is to try and fix that it was not working.

Comment: Ok. As i said in comment to previous answer :-) this error about converting parameters on client side. When parameters passed to Oracle there are no need for conversion.

Comment: yeah, but how to fix that problem? c# sends date type (datetime to be exact), oracle expects date type. what can i do? :P

Comment: I think this is in string format, not DateTime. Which engine you use for database access?

Answer (score 2):

as your column is of type `DATE` in oracle, your insert is wrong.

you should NOT do

```
to_date(p_START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

instead just insert

```
INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
  VALUES (p_GUID, p_START_DATE, p_END_DATE);
```

by doing to_Date on a date, you're forcing conversion from date to char and back to date again. in other words, your string:

```
to_date(p_START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

is silently converted to

```
to_date(to_char(p_START_DATE, NLS_DATE_FORMAT), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

ie in your case, probably:

```
to_date(to_char(p_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

as your function inputs are %TYPE (which is good), they are also dates:

```
p_START_DATE IN ONE.START_DATE%TYPE
```

so be sure, when you pass the input into the function that you're passing in a date type and not a string.

example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE ONE
  2      (
  3      p_GUID IN ONETABLE.GUID%TYPE,
  4      p_START_DATE IN ONETABLE.START_DATE%TYPE,
  5      p_END_DATE IN ONETABLE.END_DATE%TYPE,
  6      p_RETURN OUT INTEGER
  7      )
  8  AS
  9  BEGIN
 10      INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
 11    VALUES (p_GUID, p_START_DATE, p_END_DATE);
 12      COMMIT;
 13    EXCEPTION
 14          WHEN OTHERS THEN
 15          p_RETURN:= 1;
 16  END;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var r number
SQL> exec ONE('abc', to_date('2013-05-13 12:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),  to_date('2013-05-14 01:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), :r);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from onetable;

GUID                 START_DATE         END_DATE
-------------------- ------------------ ------------------
abc                  13-may-13 12:13:14 14-may-13 01:13:14
abc                  13-may-13 12:13:14 14-may-13 01:13:14
```

vs you're implicit conversions:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE ONE
  2      (
  3      p_GUID IN ONETABLE.GUID%TYPE,
  4      p_START_DATE IN ONETABLE.START_DATE%TYPE,
  5      p_END_DATE IN ONETABLE.END_DATE%TYPE,
  6      p_RETURN OUT INTEGER
  7      )
  8  AS
  9  BEGIN
 10      INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
 11    VALUES (p_GUID, to_date(p_START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date(p_END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
 12      COMMIT;
 13
 14  END;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yy';

Session altered.

SQL> var r number
SQL> exec ONE('abc', to_date('2013-05-13 12:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),  to_date('2013-05-14 01:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), :r);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-rrrr hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from onetable;

GUID                 START_DATE           END_DATE
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
abc                  13-may-0013 00:00:00 13-may-0014 00:00:00
```

wrong dates were stored..or with a diff NLS setting:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon';

Session altered.

SQL> var r number
SQL> exec ONE('abc', to_date('2013-05-13 12:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),  to_date('2013-05-14 01:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), :r);
BEGIN ONE('abc', to_date('2013-05-13 12:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),  to_date('2013-05-14 01:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), :r); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "TEST.ONE", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: yeah, INSERT INTO ONETABLE (GUID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES (p_GUID, p_START_DATE, p_END_DATE); does not work either. this was the original. i tried to date to try and fix that. and the c# explicitly sends DateTime.Now value as DATE type.

Comment: btw this is what c# sends as DATE TYPE: inParamName=p_START_DATE; inParamValue=4/5/2013 3:13:30 PM; inParamName=p_END_DATE; inParamValue=4/5/2013 3:13:30 PM;

Comment: It's not what it sends, just visualisation of parameters. Problem not on Oracle side, but at the moment of conversion from C# values to Oracle parameters _before_ passing it to database.

Comment: @ThinkJet yes. like i said if i try and hardcode it in the oracle function it seems fine, but passing it in somehow fails :( it is driving me insane.